# Can anyone explain possible causes of these errors in the server console (for Minecraft)?

Tags: java, server, minecraft

Reposting this from a Reddit post I made as I've had no response and still have no idea. Would really appreciate some guidance.

### Summary: My test server has randomly decided to not load particular function files of my datapack that had previously worked before. The server console is saying it is "Not Supported."

It's likely an issue with the paper.jar file, it's put a huge block on my pack development D:
The server console is throwing the same/similar errors when trying to load a handful of function files. An example is below. I cannot share the datapack atm (private and there are 8 individual function files affected, although built using the same method), but the different files all vary in command usage, some even using execute and some not. Most/all use the trigger command in some way and commenting those commands out in some doesn't fix the issue for every function.
**Edit: I have very little understanding of Java so simpler explanations/extra pointers would be very appreciated**

Other Details:

- Function Permission Level is set to 3 in the server.properties file (default is usually 2)
- Everything worked fine when I last worked on this, so there must be some update that has changed something I am oblivious to.
- The (Test) server is running on 1.17.1 Paper
- I've had a look at similar issues, and had little luck. The only reasonable suggestion was the permission level of functions
- Some functions are set to execute via an advancement, and then target the player using the @s selector which worked like a treat in the past. The datapack is to support multiple players

````
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314) ~[?:?]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319) ~[?:?]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1766) ~[?:?]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[?:?]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[?:?]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.commands.ICommandListener$1.getBukkitSender(ICommandListener.java:30) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.commands.CommandListenerWrapper.getBukkitSender(CommandListenerWrapper.java:322) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.commands.CommandDispatcher.lambda$new$0(CommandDispatcher.java:210) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at com.mojang.brigadier.tree.CommandNode.canUse(CommandNode.java:78) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.parseNodes(CommandDispatcher.java:358) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.parseNodes(CommandDispatcher.java:388) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.parseNodes(CommandDispatcher.java:388) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.parseNodes(CommandDispatcher.java:392) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.parseNodes(CommandDispatcher.java:392) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.parse(CommandDispatcher.java:348) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.commands.CustomFunction.a(CustomFunction.java:61) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.CustomFunctionManager.lambda$reload$3(CustomFunctionManager.java:86) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Paper-"08f746f"]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1764) ~[?:?]
27.08 16:26:02 [Server] INFO ... 3 more```
````

Comment: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.` This to me looks like the sort of error you get when a developer hasn't actually finished the code.  Better check that no classes are throwing this error.

Comment: Would this be regarding code to the server files itself @markspace? The way the function files work are like scripts that are executed to run ingame commands, which these specific files did so perfectly fine beforehand. What I mean is that I'm fairly sure my files (the ones in question above) are complete, so it must be an issue with something elsewhere that is not working well with what I am trying to do?

Comment: If I'm reading the stack trace right, it's at`net.minecraft.commands.ICommandListener$1.getBukkitSender`, specifically the ListenerWrapper class it uses.  So either that class, or one of the classes it invokes.  The stack trace also appears to be saying that the problem is in a Jar file "git-Paper.jar" with some version information attached.

Comment: If it were me, I would put all the source files (that's the text, not the Jar files) on my hard drive and run this command and see what pops up: `find -name *.java -print0 | xargs -0 grep UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: I'll see what I can do about that @markspace thanks for the tip, just an fyi (I have just updated the post) I have almost no understanding of java so any extra guidance you can hand over to me would be appreciated :) Ofc if you have any other ideas of potential causes I am open ears

Comment: What you have now is 100% absolutely code that is still in development and not ready for release.  I'd make sure you're using a "stable" release and not a development branch, then contact the authors and ask what they recommend.  If the authors are unavailable it's abandon ware and will never be ready for release without some serious development work.

Comment: Yes, prefer stable version as dev. The dev team is already working, so I suggest you to open an issue on the [paper github](https://github.com/PaperMC/Paper) and see what is her answer

Comment: Looks like someone already opened an issue for this and I completely missed it when I looked, [here it is](https://github.com/PaperMC/Paper/issues/6496). Will use that issue from now on thanks everyone

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to check if the option `settings.load-startup-plugin-commands` appear in your `paper.yml` file and is set to true.

Also it seems to be [Paper](https://github.com/PaperMC/Paper) issue that have [Pull](https://github.com/PaperMC/Paper/pull/6480) [Request](https://github.com/PaperMC/Paper/pull/6641) waiting for merge to fix it.

So I suggest you to wait until both are done, and download the latest Paper version sometimes to check if it's better now.